# Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /application, because request parameters have already been read

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, payara

I have setup the environment with :

org.springframework.boot 3.1.0
openJDK 17.0.2
Payara Server 6.2023.5

The Spring application can be started successfully with the following pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
              <!-- War plugin configuration goes here -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then I setup the RequestMapping as following:

```
    @Controller
    public class UiController {                
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String showDefault() { 
        return "<p>Hello World</p>";
    }
      
}
```

The "Hello World" can be shown successfully but the following warning is logged:

> [2023-05-30T15:06:38.410+0000] [Payara 6.2023.5] [WARNING] [AS-WEB-CORE-00059] [jakarta.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=79 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(3)] [timeMillis: 1685459198410] [levelValue: 900] [[Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context /application, because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called]]

it keeps showing a message and alert that the encoding cannot be changed, but I haven't try to change the encoding in the function and the application also haven't called the getReader. I tried to test the "GetMapping" as well but the similar warning is get. I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Fredrik mentioned that the root cause of the issue is the encoding mismatch between Jakarta (UTF-8) and Spring (ISO-8859-1). However, modifying the properties file alone cannot resolve the problem. To enforce Spring to encode it as UTF-8, I need to add the following code:

Add the line

```
addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
```

in the SecurityFilterChain, and include the following encoding configuration:

```
@Bean
public CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
   CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
   filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
   filter.setForceEncoding(true);
   return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Payara and Spring does not agree on the request character encoding. Spring probably defaults to iso-8859-1 and reads the request parameters before Payara gets a chance.

You could try to specify UTF-8 as your request character encoding in your RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "plain/text;charset=UTF-8")
```

or set it globally in your application.properties file:

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```